# My friend the musician

Tags: meaning

what does "My friend the musician" mean?

my friend is the musician OR my musician friend or somethings else?

Comment: Never ask what something means without providing the context.

Comment: It was only a title of a conversation.

Comment: *It was only a title of a conversation* This was written? Please provide the source. We cannot read into people's minds without knowing what was said beforehand and after.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No need to read into anyone's mind. It's elementary.

Comment: @Kris then post an answer. The phrase, in my opinion, can be interpreted in more than one way but I welcome your input. I commented in order to encourage the OP to add more details and to clarify.

Comment: @Mari-LouA See below. See also [ell.se]

Comment: @Kris `See also English Language Learners` Hahahaha (that was sarcastic laughing btw) And in the same way "my friend the musician" can also be used sarcastically or as a formal announcement/introduction. It could also be simply stating a fact. Or maybe it was said in good humor with a smile or a laugh? Maybe the friend  can't play a musical instrument to save his or her life, and the speaker used the phrase to rub that in. **Context** is necessary in order to ascertain the speaker's meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The following four phrases have different meanings:

1. "My friend *the musician*"
   [Restrictive modifier](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Commas.html): among your friends, this one is a musician. You might say this if you wanted to use your friend as an authority.
2. "My friend, *the musician*,"
   Non-restrictive modifier: you can remove "the musician" without changing the meaning. You might say this if you wanted to add some background color.
3. "My *friend* is the musician"
   Suggests that not you, but your friend, is the musician. You might say this if someone asked you to play the piano.
4. "My *musician* friend"
   Among your friends, this one is a musician. See above.

Comment: As the OP has clarified, it's the title of a work. There could be only one way it can be understood in the given situation. In any case, the title is clearly just one of the above. Mentioning the others is irrelevant and in fact, digressing.

Comment: Yes. Plus, as mentioned in a comment under the question, it could be meant sarcastically or in some other sense too. Without a broader context, we don't know what is actually meant.